# using ID of first entry in second entry c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have this code: It creates entry in user table with UserID = 1
At the same time It creates entry in secondTable with secondTable.UserId supposed to be one , but instead of that secondTable.UserId = -2147482647
Why does this happen ?

```
_context.Users.Add(user);
SecondTable secondTable = new SecondTable();
secondTable.UserId = user.Id;  
_context.SecondTables.Add(secondTable);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call _context.SaveChanges() after adding user to commit database.

```
_context.Users.Add(user);
_context.SaveChanges(); //add this code
SecondTable secondTable = new SecondTable();
secondTable.UserId = user.Id;  
_context.SecondTables.Add(secondTable);
_context.SaveChanges();
```